# iterating over a postgresql table and updating rows from python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using python 3 and psycopg2 to connect to a postgresql table.

the table has two column: the first is some changing string and the second is an empty string.

I want to go over all rows and for each row, read the string in the first column, compute some python-implemented function on it, and update the second column with that result.

what would be the most efficient (and hopefully the idiomatic) way to do it?

please assume I must connect to the db from python.

Comment: i am at design stage. just want a recommendation for the approach to take

Comment: Design suggestion - if at all possible, whatever that computation is, do it in SQL not in python.  If you can do your computation in SQL then you can do everything in one UPDATE statement.  If you have to do it in python, then your design must be to query all rows, and issue updates as you go.

Comment: as emphasized, I cannot cannot do it in sql and need to do it from python

Comment: @eyaler: Your question doesn't emphasize--or even *say*--that you cannot do it in SQL.

Comment: @eyaler May I ask why can't you do it in SQL instead of Python? You might be surprised at what is possible. Also, PostgreSQL allows you to call [Python functions from SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpython-funcs.html), which may also be an option for you; it's called [plpython](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpython.html).

Comment: I have permission restrictions on the db side. cannot do plpython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is probably to dump the single column out to a text file using COPY, feed it through python, truncate the table, and then load the resulting two columns back in with COPY.

Answer (score 2):

If doing the update in pure SQL is not an option, I would recommend using a **named psycopg cursor**, which will chunk your select query. You can then iterate over the cursor using a standard Python `for row in cursor` loop and it will automatically pull new rows in as needed (this will prevent memory issues if the table is quite large).

It will also be critical to have an index such that each update is as fast as possible (even for smaller tables, a sequential scan that takes, say, 200 ms vs. 2 ms will add up fast).

Lastly, I would recommend batching commits if possible, possibly in conjunction with your named-cursor's chunk size (default is 2000), since commits are expensive, and doing a commit after each row iteration will quickly add up.

You could tweak your select to only pull in rows where the 2nd column is an empty string so that the code is restartable if you want to run it multiple times due to error, new data, etc.